# Sharepoint 2013 Provisioning App part doesn't work with page propagation

Tags: sharepoint, provisioning, propagation

I have been using Sharepoint 2013 and I need a multi-language site (English and French). I'm having issue to provision App Parts in my default layout. Here is the elements.xml of my layouts :

```
<File Path="MyLayoutFolder\MyLayout.aspx" Url="MyLayoutFolder/MyLayout.aspx" Type="GhostableInLibrary" IgnoreIfAlreadyExists="TRUE">
      <Property Name="Title" Value="MyLayout"/>
      <Property Name="Description" Value="MyLayout Description"/>
      <Property Name="ContentType" Value="$Resources:cmscore,contenttype_pagelayout_name;"/>
      <Property Name="PublishingPreviewImage" Value="~SiteCollection/_catalogs/masterpage/$Resources:core,Culture;/Preview Images/ArticleLeft.png, ~SiteCollection/_catalogs/masterpage/$Resources:core,Culture;/Preview Images/ArticleLeft.png"/>
      <Property Name="PublishingAssociatedContentType" Value=";#CNPage;#0x010100C568DB52D9D0A14D9B2FDCC96666E9F2007948130EC3DB064584E219954237AF3900523C43D792F54F6FBC9E0AD0F7CCFDAF;#"/>
      <AllUsersWebPart WebPartZoneID="ContentZoneID" WebPartOrder="1">
        <![CDATA[
          <webParts>
            <webPart xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v3">
              <metaData>
                <type name="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.ClientWebPart, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" />
                <importErrorMessage>Cannot import this Web Part.</importErrorMessage>
              </metaData>
              <data>
                <properties>
                  <property name="TitleIconImageUrl" type="string" />
                  <property name="HelpMode" type="helpmode">Navigate</property>
                  <property name="Direction" type="direction">NotSet</property>
                  <property name="ExportMode" type="exportmode">None</property>
                  <property name="HelpUrl" type="string" />
                  <property name="Hidden" type="bool">False</property>
                  <property name="Description" type="string">My App Part Description</property>
                  <property name="FeatureId" type="System.Guid, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">c6df9bdd-1ed9-42fa-9589-de2b480596b9</property>
                  <property name="CatalogIconImageUrl" type="string" />
                  <property name="Title" type="string">This is the title</property>
                  <property name="AllowHide" type="bool">True</property>
                  <property name="ProductWebId" type="System.Guid, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">d624e943-f118-4c9e-9168-92566f483452</property>
                  <property name="AllowZoneChange" type="bool">True</property>
                  <property name="ChromeType" type="chrometype">None</property>
                  <property name="AllowConnect" type="bool">True</property>
                  <property name="Width" type="unit" />
                  <property name="Height" type="unit" />
                  <property name="WebPartName" type="string">WebPartName</property>
                  <property name="TitleUrl" type="string" />
                  <property name="AllowEdit" type="bool">True</property>
                  <property name="AllowMinimize" type="bool">True</property>
                  <property name="ProductId" type="System.Guid, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">c6df9bdd-1ed9-42fa-9589-de2b480596b8</property>
                  <property name="AllowClose" type="bool">True</property>
                  <property name="ChromeState" type="chromestate">Normal</property>
                </properties>
              </data>
            </webPart>
          </webParts>
        ]]>
      </AllUsersWebPart></file>
```

A few things to note. The ProductID property matches the product ID of the my App. The WebPartName match the name of my App Part. The FeatureId is the productid + 1.

When I create a page in english, my app part is created automatically. If I switch to French and I create a page, my app part is created automatically as well. However, if my french page is created automatically by the Variations Propagate Page Job Definition timer job, the app part is not created in French.

Anyone else having this issue?

Comment: You need to check the Variation settings for this. "Update Target Page Web Parts" specifies whether WebPart changes to be upgraded to the targeted pages. When the update is made, WebPart personalization will be lost. By Selecting "Update Web Part changes to target pages when variation source page update is propagated" changes will be updated.

Comment: The settings "Update Web Part changes to target pages when variation source page update is propagated" is already checked and it doesn't work